# Program doesn't display Linked list but creates a linked list in c

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am weak in linked list so please help me:

My LinkedList is not displaying on screen(display function isn't working correctly) even the linked list is creating successfully and if i use `node *head` as a global pointer to structure and if i replaced `list->head` with `head` (which is the address of `node *head`) and `LinkedList *list` (in argument of function) with `node *head`, then it is printing the whole list but if i use `list->head` or `list` in place of `head` (which is the address of `node *head`) and declared `LinkedList *list` in term of `node *head` then it input the value in linked list but don't display the linked list.

The code which causing problem is following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

typedef struct LinkedList_
 {
   node *head;
 } LinkedList;


 void create( LinkedList *list ){

     char choice='y';
     do{

        node *newnode,*temp;
        newnode=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));
        printf("\nenter the data: ");
        scanf("%d",&newnode->data);
        newnode->next=NULL;
        if(list==NULL){
            list->head=newnode;
            temp=newnode;
        }
        else{
            temp=list->head;
            while(temp->next!=NULL){
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            temp->next=newnode;
        }
        printf("\ndo you want to continue(y or no)?  ");
        choice=getche();

        }while(choice=='y');
 }


 void display( LinkedList *list ){
     printf("\n[");
     while(list->head!=NULL){
          printf("%d,",list->head->data);
          list->head=list->head->next;
     }
     printf("]");
 }


void main(){
     LinkedList *head=NULL;
     create(head);
     display(head);
}
```

Comment: "Not familiar with the rules/policy of stackoverflow if there is any." - After 11 months you should have taken the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: this is my second or third time posting question and i don't visit stack overflow often

Comment: Ignorantia legis non excusat

Comment: okay so what's my punishment for violating a rule even i was unaware of?

Comment: `newnode=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));` --> `newnode = malloc(sizeof *newnode);`

Comment: `if(list==NULL){ list->head=newnode;` That should crash the program with a segfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

typedef struct LinkedList_ {
    node *head;
} LinkedList;

 void create( LinkedList *list ){
    char choice='y';
    if(!list || list->head){//guard
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid call %s.\n", __func__);
        return;
    }

    node *temp;
    do{
        node *newnode;
        newnode = malloc(sizeof(*newnode));//or malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("\nenter the data: ");
        scanf("%d", &newnode->data);
        newnode->next = NULL;
        if(list->head == NULL){
            list->head = newnode;
            temp = newnode;
        } else {
            temp = temp->next = newnode;//There is no need to follow the link
        }
        printf("\ndo you want to continue(y or no)?  ");
        choice=getche();
    }while(choice=='y');
}


 void display( LinkedList *list ){
    node *curr = list->head;//head should not be changed
    printf("\n[");
    while(curr != NULL){
          printf("%d,", curr->data);
          curr = curr->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

int main(void){
    LinkedList head = { NULL };//requires entity
    create(&head);
    display(&head);
}
```